# See output from unit test in visual studio 2015 without using the mouse

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, output, keyboard-shortcuts

With this snippet of code

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplicationUnitTest
{
    public class Msg
    {
        public static string ID = "5";
        public static string CON = "Console.WriteLine";
        public static string DEB = "System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine";
    }
    [Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestClass]
    public class MyTestClass
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestHelloWorld()
        {
            Program.Main(new string[] {""});
            String Source = " Test: ";
            Console.WriteLine(Msg.ID + Source + Msg.CON);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Msg.ID + Source + Msg.DEB);
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String Source = " Main: ";
            Console.WriteLine(Msg.ID + Source + Msg.CON);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Msg.ID + Source + Msg.DEB);
            //Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> (to build).

I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> (to run the test).

I fumble around for the mouse, while swearing, and click the output link in TestExplorer.

[image]

Because, if I don't, the old Test Output window will just sit there continuing to look like this:

[image]

When what I need to see is this:

[image]

My question: How do I see the up-to-date Test Output without having to touch the mouse?